# API implementation changes for OpenCV 3.0 instead of OpenCV 2.4

Tags: opencv, upgrade, opencv3.0

I'm trying to update from OpenCV2.4.10 to OpenCV3.0.0. [OpenCV provides a basic guide](http://docs.opencv.org/ref/master/db/dfa/tutorial_transition_guide.html) for how general APIs work after the update, however, it doesn't cover how to deal with some implementation and API changes that have been removed completely. Is there a definitive guide to this process?

For example, one specific problem I'm encountering is that [a library I'm using calls a function that has been removed from OpenCV3](https://github.com/hengli/camodocal/blob/d646c8f0a8302a6851fbfdbcc164d6ea91920c73/src/npoint/five-point/modelest.cpp#L190):

```
static CV_IMPLEMENT_QSORT( icvSortDistances, int, CV_LT )
```

How can I replace [CV_IMPLEMENT_QSORT](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/2.4/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/internal.hpp#L461)? It appears to be originally defined in [cxtypes](http://note.sonots.com/OpenCV/cxtypes.html) according to this blog post. There is another similar function of note [CV_DECLARE_QSORT](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/2.4/apps/haartraining/_cvcommon.h), which may also not be in 3.0?

Also several components use the opencv legacy libraries, are there any known or suggested upgrade paths for those?

Comment: what is the problem for downloading the library 3.0 directly ?

Comment: Also where  is this function `CV_IMPLEMENT_QSORT` defined?

Comment: @CroCo updated my question with the information you asked for, at least as well as I could find it.

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/ref/master/db/dfa/tutorial_transition_guide.html

Comment: @berak Thanks! incorporated that into my question too. It is useful but it doesn't cover some of the important underlying changes.

Comment: were you able to find an alternative way?

Comment: @Maystro I did make changes to [get everything to compile with OpenCV 3.0](https://github.com/ahundt/camodocal/commit/abe750c279f57b5bca6bda1079adda4ce69add6c). You can check that out for some ideas on what to do. I don't have time at the moment to write a full answer yet, but I plan to when I get a chance.

Comment: @Andrew Hund thanks.. Will check it then

Answer (score 0):

How about replacing it with :

```
static void icvSortDistances(int *array, size_t total, int )
{
    std::sort(&array[0], &array[total]);
}
```